# How do iterators map/know their current position or element

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

Consider the following code example :

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10, 2);
    std::partial_sum(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), v.begin());
    std::cout << "Among the numbers: ";
    std::copy(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';

    if (std::all_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; })) {
        std::cout << "All numbers are even\n";
    }
    if (std::none_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::bind(std::modulus<int>(), 
                                                     std::placeholders::_1, 2))) {
        std::cout << "None of them are odd\n";
    }
    struct DivisibleBy
    {
        const int d;
        DivisibleBy(int n) : d(n) {}
        bool operator()(int n) const { return n % d == 0; }
    };

    if (std::any_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), DivisibleBy(7))) {
        std::cout << "At least one number is divisible by 7\n";
    }
}
```

If we look at this part of the code :

```
if (std::all_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; })) {
            std::cout << "All numbers are even\n";
        }
```

which is fairly easy to understand. It iterates over those vector elements , and finds out `i%2==0` , whether they are completely divisible by 2 or not , hence finds out they're even or not.

Its for loop counterpart could be something like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i<v.size();++i){
    if(v[i] % 2 == 0) areEven = true;    //just for readablity
    else areEven = false;
}
```

---

In this for loop example , it is quiet clear that the current element we're processing is `i` since we're actually accessing `v[i]`. But how come in iterator version of same code , it maps `i` or knows what its current element is that we're accessing?

How does `[](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; })` ensures/knows that i is the current element which iterator is pointing to.

I'm not able to makeout that without use of any `v.currently_i_am_at_this_posiition()` , how is iterating done. I know what iterators are but I'm having a hard time grasping them. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating is done by using an [iterator object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/)

> An iterator is any object that, pointing to some element in a range of
>   elements (such as an array or a container), has the ability to iterate
>   through the elements of that range using a set of operators (with at
>   least the increment (++) and dereference (*) operators).
>
> **The most obvious form of iterator is a pointer**: A pointer can point to
>   elements in an array, and can iterate through them using the increment
>   operator (++).

and advancing it through the set of elements. The `std::all_of` function in your code is roughly equivalent to the following code

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
bool c_all_of(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (!p(*first)) {
            return false; // Found an odd element!
        }
    }
    return true; // All elements are even
}
```

An iterator, when incremented, keeps track of the currently pointed element, and when dereferenced it returns the value of the currently pointed element.

*For teaching's and clarity's sake*, you might also think of the operation as follows (don't try this at home)

```
bool c_all_of(int* firstElement, size_t numberOfElements, std::function<bool(int)> evenTest)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i)
        if (!evenTest(*(firstElement + i)))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Notice that iterators are a powerful abstraction since they allow consistent elements access in different containers (e.g. `std::map`).

Comment: doing `[](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; })` inside `std::any_of` , how does it knows that i being used inside lambda is actually the value of current iterator? is this some property of lamda functions?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal i is **NOT** the index into the vector, it is **the element** of the vector, i.e. the iterator dereferenced or a pointer to an element dereferenced

Comment: Oh okay. This clears much of my confusion. Just 1 last question , when actually was `i` transfered the value of current pointer/iterator? when it was passed into lamda?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Before the lambda is called, a pointer/iterator/whatever pointing to the right element is dereferenced. The lambda automatically gets the right value as its parameter. The code that dereferences the iterator/pointer/whatever is written in one of the standard library headers (it is not important to know which line and column does that).

Answer (score 4):

Iterators are modeled after pointers, and that's it really. How they work internally is of no interest, but a *possible* implementation is to actually have a pointer inside which points to the current element.